# SimpleDateFormat to get desired output

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to have an output like below

```
Nov 4, 2003 8:14 PM
```

How i can achieve it with simpleddateformat?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Follow this  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html and do it your self

Comment: i thought doing the following will result in desired output DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT).format(now)

Comment: You should read javadoc before asking question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, YYYY hh:mm a");
```

Please read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
Date date = new Date(); //expected date to display
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a");
System.out.print(format.format(date));
```

Thanks!